# Accidentally removed windows when dual booting (Ubuntu re-install wiped partitions)

Tags: data-recovery

I am not sure if this question is appropriate to be posted here but I have really no idea and I really need to fix this problem ASAP and I am so frustrated right now. I was dual booting windows 8.1 with ubuntu and after a successful installation in which both OSes boot fine, I installed gnome on Ubuntu and I could not get Ubuntu booting again, so I decided to reinstall Ubuntu but I didn't know that the reinstall and wipe data option will remove the Windows drive. Now I am left with Ubuntu but I still need Windows as my primary OS, I have backup up a system image of Windows 8.1 and my question is how to restore from that, loosing Ubuntu isn't an issue, any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Manager Partitions

1. Install GParted if necessary by running `sudo apt-get install gparted`;
2. Down-size your Ubuntu partition to create some free space;
3. Create a new partition and format it as NTFS;

### [Install Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) [from a Recovery Disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsRecoveryCd)

Some computer manufacturers that pre-install Windows provide a Windows recovery/re-installation CD or DVD with the computer. However, many companies no longer ship a physical disc but instead create a hidden partition on the hard drive in which the recovery-disk information is stored. A utility is then usually provided which allows the user to burn a recovery/re-installation CD or DVD from it. If you are buying a new computer and intend on dual-booting, make sure you have (or can make) a physical Windows recovery/re-installation CD or DVD. If neither a CD/DVD nor a recovery partition/burning utility is provided by your computer manufacturer, you may need to contact your vendor and ask for a CD or DVD (to which you are normally entitled under the Windows EULA).

You may need to request a physical recovery/re-installation Cd or Dvd directly from your computer manufacturer. Here are some resources:

1. [Dell Operating System (OS) Recovery CD Creation and Manual Operating System Reinstall](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/document?c=us&cs=19&docid=287034&l=en&s=dhs&redirect=1#7)
2. [Other related links and information for Dell owners](http://support.dell.com/pcrt)
3. [Lenovo Product Recovery CD or DVD](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-4M7HWZ)
4. [Getting recovery CDs from IBM for a Thinkpad](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2006/01/18/ibm-lenovo-thinkpad-recovery-cd/)
5. [Obtaining a Windows Recovery CD or DVD set for HP and Compaq PCs](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/genericDocument?cc=us&docname=bph07143&lc=en)

### Configure Bootloader

Windows 8, being an inconsiderate/ignorant OS, ignores the possibility of dual-booting; and just replaced your boot-loader. Reconfigure GRUB 2 [using a USB or DVD](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lod8sRb_6I).

Comment: Thank you first. But how can I install windows 8? My laptop comes with Windows 8 pre-installed and I don't have a disk. Or can I install Windows from the back up image?

Comment: In my case, my backup image is stored on an external hard drive, so can i install Windows or burn it to a CD or something i can install Windows with it?

Comment: @xXJJJasonMokXx Refer to the new section I added.

Comment: I've read through all the pages you kindly provided but none of them seems to work for me cause again, I don't even have a windows CD, or is it possible to make or burn one with the backup system image?

Comment: @xXJJJasonMokXx AFAIK, it's not. I would suggest reading the sites the second header is linked to; or, if nothing else works, torrent a disk image and burn it to a DVD.

Comment: Also, if you felt my answer was helpful in any way; please upvote it by clicking on the arrows to the left of the answer.

Comment: I think I'll go for the "custom installation cd" :). Anyway, thank you guys, I'll keep you updated!!! :D

Comment: yeah i'd love to upvote your answer for your awesome assistant, but I only have enough reputation for upvoting in stackoverflow, no in askubuntu however. I can still accept the answer :D

Comment: @xXJJJasonMokXx Oh yeah, hadn't thought of that. I was glad to be of help.

Comment: BTW, be sure to edit this answer with w/e approach you tried/worked for you.

Comment: Yeah sure i will, would love to help out others like me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14137/discussion-between-xxjjjasonmokxx-and-yatharthrock)

Comment: I finally am able to reinstall windows with a installation disk from my friend

Answer (score 0):

Install Windows following the above mentioned procedure and while installing leave a certain amount of space(in GB)for installing Ubuntu in that space.

After you have succesfully installed Windows then install Ubuntu in the space u have left earlier.Now after you have done that you will see that only ubuntu is loading but not windows but don't panick. Load Boot Loader in an USB drive (the procedure is well explainded here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair ) and then click the recommended repair option.That will definately recover your Grub2 and you will see both of your operating system in the boot option.

Hope it will help you.If you have any problem in any step feel free to ask anytime.

Comment: Same issue as above, i only have my windows backup image on an external hard drive, so what can i do with it?